# Is it possible to load wp-content/uploads from another server?

Tags: multisite, cdn

I just recently moved to my new CentOS server and I did a fresh installed and before I use to be with my Mac OS [Xserver]

So what happen I was thinking about CDN and though that maybe this will somehow apply to some of the condition where it will make my site load faster because this is from another server.

How or is it even possible for me to get the wp-content/uploads from another server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use any number of CDN plugins http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=CDN  or a cache plugin that also suports a CDN like WP Super Cache http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/

Answer (score 1):

you can manually put this on your wp-config.php::

```
define( 'MYUPLOADSPATH', '\\\\myserver\myfolder' );
define( 'MYCDNURL', 'http://cdn.mydomain.com' );
```

and this on your functions.php:

```
update_option('upload_path', MYUPLOADSPATH);
update_option('upload_url_path', MYCDNURL);
```